# FIND THE PERFECT NUMBER IN PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

I do have an answer already but I'm curious if there's a better method on coding this problem through python. Thank you.

A number is called a perfect number if it is equal to the sum of all of its divisors, not including
the number itself. For instance, 6 is a perfect number because the divisors of 6 are 1, 2, 3, 6
and 6 = 1 + 2 + 3. As another example, 28 is a perfect number because its divisors are 1, 2, 4,
7, 14, 28 and 28 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14. However, 15 is not a perfect number because its divisors
are 1, 3, 5, 15 and 15 6= 1 + 3 + 5. Write a program that finds all four of the perfect numbers
that are less than 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer.

```
for i in range(1,10000):
    
 summ = 0 
    
    for m in range(i):
        if i % (m+1) == 0:
            summ = summ + (m+1)
        g = summ - i
        
    if g == i :
        print(g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is perfect number algorithm that checks for perfect numbers using the Lucas Lehmer Test:

```
def ffs(x):
    return (x&-x).bit_length()-1

def levelx(N, withstats=False):
  if N <= 1: return False
  temp = N
  newlevel = temp.bit_length()
  primetest = temp//(2**(ffs(temp)))
  offset = temp//primetest
  s = 4
  
  nextlevel = newlevel // 2
  
  check = temp // (2**nextlevel)

  prevtemp = 2**nextlevel

  if withstats == True:
    print (newlevel, newlevel, temp)
    print (newlevel, nextlevel+one, prevtemp)
 
        
  if (prevtemp & (prevtemp-1) == 0) and prevtemp != 0:
       if offset.bit_length() == primetest.bit_length():
          if ((primetest+1) & ((primetest+1)-1) == 0):
             for x in range(primetest.bit_length()-1):
               s = (s * s - 2) % primetest
               if withstats == True:
                  print(s)
               if s in [0,2]: return True
             return False
          else: return False
       else: return False
  else: return False
```

Here is the output:

```
In [645]: for x in range(2,100): 
     ...:     if levelx((2**(x-1))*(2**x-1)) == True: 
     ...:        print(x, (2**(x-1))*(2**x-1)) 
     ...:         
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                           
2 6
3 28
5 496
7 8128
13 33550336
17 8589869056
19 137438691328
31 2305843008139952128
61 2658455991569831744654692615953842176
89 191561942608236107294793378084303638130997321548169216
```

You  can use gmpy2 to speed these up by about 10x.

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in range(1,10000):
    sum=0
    for I in range(1,J):
        if J%I==0:
            sum= sum + I
    if j==sum:
        print(J," is a perfect square")
```

Comment: Hello, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help Thanks!